# How to set a Reminder on iOS5 for a location AND date?

Tags: ios, geolocation, reminders

I'd like to set a Reminder on iOS5 for my iPhone 4 for when I leave work on Friday... However, the app seems to allow only location OR date/time notifications (or you can have both independently). Is there any way to get them to work in conjunction with one another as I'd like?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. The Location and Time conditions are applied in a disjunctive manner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have a source?